# Python Web Api to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am looking for some assistance with writing API results to a .CSV file using Python.

I have my source as CSV file. It contains the below urls in a column as separate rows.

- https://webapi.nhtsa.gov/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/2013/make/Acura/model/rdx?format=csv
- https://webapi.nhtsa.gov/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/2017/make/Chevrolet/model/Corvette?format=csv

I can call the Web API and get the printed results. Please find attached 'Web API results' snapshot.

[image: Web API results]

When I try to export these results into a csv, I am getting them as per the attached 'API results csv'. It is not transferring all the records. Right now, It is only sending the last record to csv.

[image: API results csv]

My final output should be as per the attached 'My final output should be' for all the given inputs.

[image: My Final Output Should be]

Please find the below python code that I have used. I appreciate your help on this. Please find attached image for my code.[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOP3y.png)

```py
import csv, requests
with open('C:/Desktop/iva.csv',newline ='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        urls = row[0]
        print(urls)
        r = requests.get(urls)
        print (r.text)
                with open('C:/Desktop/ivan.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
                       csvfile.write(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a writer object of the csvfile(to be created). and use the writerow() method you could write to the csvfile.

```
import csv,requests
with open('C:/Desktop/iva.csv',newline ='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        urls = row[0]
        print(urls)
        r = requests.get(urls)
        print (r.text)
with open('C:/Desktop/ivan.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writerobj=csv.writer(r.text)
    for line in reader:
        writerobj.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Tried with the above code but got the below error.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-dc7cb6851ae6>", line 12, in <module>
    writerobj=csvfile.writer(r.text)

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writer'

Comment: I modified the code to below and brings all the data into single line in the csv . Is there a way to split in to multiple rows?


import csv, requests
with open('C:/iva.csv','r', newline = '') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
     urls = row[0]
     print(urls)
     r = requests.get(urls, proxies = proxies)
     print (r.text)
     filename = 'C:/Desktop/ivan.csv'
     with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
         file_object.write(r.text)

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is that every time you open a file using `open` and mode `w`, any existing content in that file will be lost. You could prevent that by using append mode `open(filename, 'a')` instead.

But even better. Just open the output file once, outside the for loop.

```
import csv, requests
with open('iva.csv') as infile, open('ivan.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        r = requests.get(urls[0])
        outfile.write(r.text)
```